# Assigning event handlers to dynamically generated controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

There is an issue that I've been struggling with it which is I generate a button in page load event and I assign a new handler for it but the event is not executed.

I cannot spot the problem.

If there are better ways to do this assignment please inform me about it.

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button edit = new Button();
    edit.Text = "edit";
    edit.ID = "editbtn";
    edit.Click += new EventHandler(this.edit_Click);
    info.Controls.Add(edit);
}

protected void edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");

}
```

And info is an existing asp panel on my page.

Comment: Try creating the control in `Page.OnInit` instead.

Comment: @Magnus Again it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set an `Id` to the control.

Comment: @Magnus same result

Comment: Just for testing purposes you can try to add the control to Page instead of info. Otherwise I'm out of ideas on this. 
The creation of the object should not be wrapped in any `if(!Page.IsPostback)..` but you don't seem to have that in your code.

Comment: I would put the code in the panel and hide/unhide the panel based on your needs. Can't really see the use for setting the button on page_load. Just let me know if you need code example.

Comment: @chrillelundmark my dear friend your approach for resolving this is great and wise and i already know about this but the plot of my original code is that i'm retrieving users' data on cms and this piece of code that i am asking is just a example of the setback that i'm confronting with it. The point is retriving data for each user and creating their own specific button and panel and so on so i have to create controlls dynamicly and assign them the appropiriate function i hope you percieve what i said. If there is anything uncanny for you in this let me know to spell it out